# String.isSubstring dosnt work - sml

Tags: substring, sml

I want to check if a line contains a specific word, so I tried to use the String.isSubstring function with the line and the specific word. But somehow that function dosn't work for me.

`String.isSubstring("Hi my name is...", "name");
stdIn:2.1-2.47 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: string
  operand:         string * string
  in expression:
    String.isSubstring ("Hi my name is...","name")
-`

I will love if some one can tell me what did i do wrong?
Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String.isSubstring` is a curried function -- that is, its arguments are passed in separately, not as a tuple.

Try

```
String.isSubstring "Hi my name is..." "name"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I tried it: String.isSubstring "Hi my name is..." "name". and it returned false...

Comment: OK it works... the first argument must be the substring and the second the string. thank you very much